# What does ShmemHugePages mean?

Tags: meminfo

I'm using `grep Huge /proc/meminfo` and getting:

```
AnonHugePages:     16384 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:      33
HugePages_Free:       18
HugePages_Rsvd:       18
HugePages_Surp:        1
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

What does `ShmemHugePages` means/refers to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `proc(5)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) says

> (`CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` is required.)  Memory used
>                        by shared memory (shmem) and [`tmpfs(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) allocated with
>                        huge pages

`ShmemHugePages` counts the number of huge pages which are used for share memory allocations, or `tmpfs`. Huge pages are pages which are larger than the “standard” page size on your platform (typically, 4KiB); they have certain benefits and disadvantages, and it’s therefore interesting to keep track of them separately. Shared memory is memory which is allocated with the intention of sharing it between multiple processes, typically allocated using [`shmget`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html) (which allows the caller to explicitly request huge pages). `tmpfs` is the RAM-based temporary file system commonly used nowadays for `/tmp` and a number of other mount points.